# How to delete file after 1 week from folder and database in laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I store the files in the public folder in a file called "files".

I want it to automatically delete the file after 1 week and it to delete it from the database.

**FileController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move(public_path("files"), $new_name);

        $upload = new File();
        $upload->ip = $request->ip();
        $upload->file_name = $new_name;
        $upload->save();

        return redirect('/file');
    }
```

**Kernal.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();

    $schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('files')->whereRaw('created_at >= now() - interval 168 hour')->delete();
    })->weekly();
}
```

Comment: where do you store the file path? where is the 'files' folder?

Comment: In the public folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add column 'automatically_delete_at' to the table, in this column you have to store date when the uploaded file will delete.

```
FileController.php

use Carbon;
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $upload = new File();
    ...
    ...
    $days_after_file_delete = 7;
    $upload->automatically_delete_at = Carbon::now()->addDays($days_after_file_delete)->format('Y-m-d');
    $upload->save();
    ...
}


Kernal.php

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
      $files = DB::table('files')->whereDate('automatically_delete_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
      here you get all files which should be delete
      ...
      your code
      ... 
    })->daily();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `files` table has a `path` field with the path inside the `public` of that file, you just need to edit the function in order to get the files to delete, and than delete that files record:

```php
$queryBuilder = DB::table('files')->whereRaw('created_at >= now() - interval 168 hour');
foreach($queryBuilder->get() as $file){
    File::delete(public_path().$file->path);
}
$queryBuilder->delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create commmand and you will get from database names with date create if you have timestamps you can use it if don't you should create column like createDate.
Take look at this:

```
 $time=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . " -7 day")); //this will give you date from last week
 $names=DB::table('files')->select('file_name')->whereRAW("date(createDate)='$time'")->get()->each(function ($file){
        unlink(public_path('files\\'.$file->file_name)) //this delete from folder
        DB::table('files')->where('file_name',$file->file_name)->delete(); //this delete from database
    });
```

For the end you should add in kernel scheduler with will be run daily.

That's all