# Delete image and database entry after one day

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to delete an image that is saved in storage/app/public after one day.
I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047517/16693518) but cannot manage to make it work. This is my first time doing anything on kernel.php so appreciate it if someone can help me figure out what Im doing wrong or if theres an easier way to do it.

**Controller**

```
// set path
$pathMedia = "/media" . "/" . $aid . '-' . uniqid() . ".jpg";

// store received image
Storage::disk("public")->put($pathMedia, $image);

// insert new received media
$media = new ReceivedMedia();
$media->media = $pathMedia;
$media->type = 'image';
$media->delete_at = Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');
$media->save();
```

**Kernel.php**

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$schedule->call(function () {
    $files = DB::table('received_media')->whereDate('delete_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $mediaPath = public_path('storage') . $file->media;
        if ($file->media != null && File::exists($mediaPath)) {
            unlink($mediaPath);
        }
        $file->delete();
    }
})->daily();
```

Comment: Did you setup task scheduler running like in the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: did you run the scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the file in Storage and trying to delete it from the public folder.

You should delete it from the storage instead of public

```
if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($file->media)) {
   Storage::disk('public')->delete($file->media);
}
```